# Xcode continuous integration stack on "building sources"

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, xcode-server

[image]

I don't know how to solve this. Is it a bug of Xcode or did I miss something?

The following are the settings of my Bot:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Does repository git path is correct?

Because I have it in `Apps/DirectBistro/.git`.

[image]

Something is not right here but I do not know what.

[image]

The error is the following:

> Build Service Error Running task was terminated because it produced no activity for more than 600 seconds (use sudo xcrun xcscontrol --configure-integration-timeout to increase this timeout)

Answer (score 0):

In our case it was due to broken permissions. It usually happens after Xcode Server or macOS update.

This can be fixed with:

```
$ sudo xcrun xcscontrol --fix-permissions
```

In case it won't help, try resetting Xcode Server (**NB!** **this will delete all your bots and history**):

```
$ sudo xcrun xcscontrol --reset
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same bug and solved it using the following steps:

1. Save all files in your project
2. Remove all files and commit
3. Add all files, commit and push
4. Remove the contents of the file `.gitignore`
5. Add all the files using `git add .`
6. Commit and push

Answer (score 0):

For my case,

- **Xcode 10**
- my build time is more than **600** seconds

> Running task was terminated because it produced no activity for 600 seconds

In Preferences > Server & Bots > Integration timeout

Increase it to more than 10 minutes

[image]